# Server side validation for non numeric data entered

Tags: struts2

I have textfield array which has to accept only numeric values i.e. 1-5.

```
<s:textfield name="marks[0]" maxlength="1" /> 
<s:textfield name="marks[1]" maxlength="1" /> 
<s:textfield name="marks[2]" maxlength="1" />  and so on upto 9 textfields.
```

I have getter/setter methods for this as follows

```
public List<Integer> getMarks(){
     return marks;
}
public void setMarks(List<Integer> marks){
     this.marks = marks;
}
```

How to ensure that user does not enter non numeric values like alphabets? If I enter character it throws runtime exception 'java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer ' pointing to validate method in the Next JSp page.

```
public void validate(){
  for(i=0;i<9;i++){
     if (marks.get(i)>5)     //this line throws above ClassCastException
    addFieldError("...");
  }
}
```

How to solve this exception as well as validation to continue? In other Pages where single textfield is there, invalid.fieldvalue.error is displayed but for List I am getting above exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put your validation logic inside `try catch` block

```
public void validate(){
  try{
    for(i=0;i<9;i++){
      if (marks.get(i)>5)     //this line throws above ClassCastException
        addFieldError("...");
    }
  }catch(Exception e){
  }
}
```

Comment: Now it is working,but I am getting 2 field errors now. One is invalid field error from the ConversionErrorInterceptor where fieldName is displayed as marks[0] or marks[1] and other one which i added in catch block using addFieldError which is clear to understand.How to display only custom message

Comment: Do not add your custom message and see this link http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/type-conversion.html#TypeConversion-TypeConversionErrorHandling.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do it that way (may be there is better solution)

```
public void setMarks(List<String> marksStr){
  List<Integer> marks = new ArrayList();

  for(String markStr : marksStr) {
    try {
      Integer mark = Integer.parseInt(markStr);
      marks.add(mark);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
      addFieldError("", "Wrong mark value: " + markStr);
    }
  }
  this.marks = marks;
}
```

Comment: Do NOT put validation logic inside setters/getters.

Comment: @Vaisly Komarov-I tried this as well but still it is throwing exception.I go with Aleksandr M that should not put validation logic inside setters/getters. Thank you for your answer, may be in some other code it may be useful for me.